# vue-router, webpack-dev-server and historyApiFallback, /foo is ok but /foo/:bar gives 404 (/foo/bundle.js)

Tags: vuejs2, webpack-dev-server, vue-router

I have a question about vue-router. How could I accomplish a route like this:

```
domain.com/confirm/randomstring
```

randomString is a token, displayed in this template:

```
const ConfirmComp = {
  template: `<div>ConfirmComp 
    <img src="img/logo.svg">
    <h3>you confirm: {{  $route.params.token  }} </h3>
  </div>`
};
```

For testing I add a link into another component:

```
<router-link :to="{path:'confirm/d4r5g6hy7'}">/confirm/something</router-link>
```

The router config:

```
export default new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    base: "/",
    routes: [
        {path: "/", component: Root},
        {path: "/suscribe", component: InscriptionComp},
        {path: "/confirm/:token", component: ConfirmComp, props: true}
    ]
});
```

Webpack devServer config:

```
conf.devServer = {
        host: "localhost",
        historyApiFallback: true,
        proxy: {
            "/api": "http://localhost:8080"
        }
    }
```

Thing 0: Adding historyApiFallback on my server helps to render page refreshs on /xxx or /yyy routes, but not with a param (/yyy/:token)

Thing 1: When navigating on the link /confirm/r5t4y7 by clicking in page:
-Component render
-Param token id displayed correctly but
-404 on the image: "/confirm/img/logo.svg" not found (should not have '/confirm')

Thing 2: When refreshing http://localhost/confirm/t3f4g5g
-Nothing works: it tries to load style.css and bundle.css with "/confirm" base instead of /

Versions: vue 2.5.16, vue-router 3.0.1, webpack 4.6.0, webpack-dev-server 3.1.3, vue-loader 15.0.7

Thanks you

Comment: this is not a problem with Router but with the server config. You should rewrite all non-existent URL paths to `/index.html`

Comment: @IVOGELOV this is allready done via "historyApiFallback: true"

Comment: If this is done then you should be able to request `/bla/bla/nothing.css` in the browser and get your `index.html` in return. If you do not get it - then the server is not properly configured.

Comment: Sure, I will take a look at this. But why my application is requesting "/xxx/bundle.js" and "xxx/style.css" ? These files are real and at root. If the server gives index.html instead of bundle.js, it will not work

Comment: Have you tried adding `/` in front of the `path` in `router-link` tag ? Usually, it is better to use named routes and refer to them by name rather than URL.

Comment: @IVOGELOV I've edited my rewriting rules for all non-existing urls. It all gives now index.html. The problem stay the same, accessing /confirm/token loads index.html, but then it load /confirm/bundle.js (instead of /bundle.js). Sounds like the base is not ok. Is this a server problem too?

Comment: Thanks you IVO. About adding / in router-link : no change, and the problem is here when typing the url durecting in browser

Comment: Well, then look inside `index.html` - where does it look for the script and CSS. If not looking in the root - then check `assetsPublicPath` and `assetsSubDirectory` in the `/config/index.js` file

Comment: Ok after setting output.publicPath = "/" (I do not haev vue template) my links are absolute, perfect. But my /api proxy doesn't work anymore. Looking at this.

Comment: Thanks you @IVOGELOV for your help. I solve my issue by adding output.publicPath = "/" and devServer.historyApiFallback = {rewrites: [{from: /.*/, to: '/index.html'}]} in webpack.config

Comment: Well, the `proxy` is usually for the case when your backend is on a different host than your frontend. If they are on the same host - there is no need for a proxy. Anyway, congrats for solving your issue :))